# .net 2.0: What's the best way to deal with in-memory DataTables?

Tags: .net, ado.net, .net-2.0, datatable, in-memory

I have a csv file that I import into a DataTable. Furthermore I've created a TableAdapter with several queries. Is it somehow possible to execute the queries associated with the TableAdapter directly on the "in-memory" DataTable (doesn't seem so) or do I always have to write the imported DataTable to the database first and then execute the TableAdapter queries on the persisted data? I wanted to use the datatable directly as it is a small project and it's not worth converting the data back and forth from value object to datatable or use OR mappers.

Thanks in advance!

Best regards,

Andreas

PS: It is only a small amount of data, so the memory impact should not be that big.

Comment: You may consider using LINQ to CSV as an alternative: http://www.codeproject.com/KB/linq/LINQtoCSV.aspx.  No mapping per se, though you'd have to create a class with  attributes.  The query flexibility would be incredible.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your question. A DataTable is a .NET construct, so it exists only in memory. I think you need to provide more information about the way you're handling the data.

Comment: I just wanted to save the roundtrip to the database (in fact no problem; my SQL Server is fast;-)). Instead of reading the csv physically into the database and then retrieve the data from the database by the queries of the tableadapter, I thought it would be nice to spare the step of physically reading and writing and do this directly. But actually it doesn't mattern.

Answer (score 3):

You can use Select method of DataTable. It takes SQL-like filter (similar to what you write in `where` clause)

```
var table = new DataTable();

table.Columns.Add("Value");

table.Rows.Add(1);
table.Rows.Add("One");

var rows = table.Select("value='One'");

foreach (var value in rows)
    Console.WriteLine(value["Value"]);
```

Comment: Thanks. I read about that. But as far as I know this works just for "simple" selects. With Compute() you can do some calculations, but for "group by"s this is quite cumbersome (http://support.microsoft.com/?scid=kb%3Ben-us%3B326145&x=3&y=12) as well as for joins (http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/adodotnetdataproviders/thread/f122d7f4-3b7d-4d93-bd0f-8bb57cd990a4/). Seems that there is no easy way to do this. So I'll have to write the data back and forth to the database. So as there isn't lots of data, it's no problem.

Answer (score 1):

Load whole file into memory and use [Linq to DataSet](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vbasic/bb688086.aspx).

The same queries could transparently work with SQL database (`Linq to SQL`) but I don't know if there's something like `Linq to CSV` or `Linq to ODBC`.

Comment: Yes, I was thinking about that. But up to now I haven't found a way to use it with VS 2005.

Comment: Google for `LinqBridge` if you want to have linq in .Net 2.0. But you better use VS2008 targeting 2.0 rather than VS2005, otherwise extension methods and lambda won't work and code will have to be ugly